# Cant seem to pass parameters without errors

Tags: c#, variables, parameter-passing, ref-parameters

I am trying to write a simple program and am unfamiliar with passing parameters through methods. This is what I have so far under the button click method but it returns errors such as: Use of unassigned local variable (for strColor, strMake, and decPrice) as well as "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" but I have all of my brackets correct. Thanks for your help!

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strColor;
        string strMake;
        decimal decPrice;

        GetColor(ref strColor);
        GetMake(ref strMake);
        GetPrice(ref decPrice);
        DisplayResult(strColor, strMake, decPrice);

        private void GetColor(ref string color){
            color = lstColor.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        private void GetMake(ref string make){
            make = lstMake.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        private void GetPrice(ref decimal price){
            if (decimal.TryParse(txtMaxPrice.Text, out price)){
            }
            else{
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid number");
            }
        }
        private void DisplayResult(string color, string make, decimal price){
            lblMessage.Text = "Color of " + color + " Make of: " + make + " " + price.ToString("c");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have declared methods within methods or Is it typo?

Comment: Thats what I did. So it was more like a typo of learning that thats not possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the [ref keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) you need to initialize the parameter passed to the called function.

So you need

```
string strColor = string.Empty;
string strMake = string.Empty;
decimal decPrice = 0;
```

Of course you cannot have a function inside another function. You should extract the methods inside the event handler of the button and put them at the same level of the `btnSubmit_Click`

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strColor;
    string strMake;
    decimal decPrice;

    GetColor(ref strColor);
    GetMake(ref strMake);
    GetPrice(ref decPrice);
    DisplayResult(strColor, strMake, decPrice);
}
private void GetColor(ref string color)
{
    color = lstColor.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
private void GetMake(ref string make)
{
    make = lstMake.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
private void GetPrice(ref decimal price)
{
    if (decimal.TryParse(txtMaxPrice.Text, out price))
    {
    }
    else
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid number");
    }
}
private void DisplayResult(string color, string make, decimal price)
{
   lblMessage.Text = "Color of " + color + " Make of: " + make + " " + price.ToString("c");
}
```

However, your use of the ref keyword seems to be pointless. Just use the return statement and change the methods to return the appropriate values and assign then to the correct variables

```
... in btnSubmit_Click

string strColor = GetColor();
string strMake = GetMake();
decimal decPrice = GetPrice();
if(decPrice != 0)
   .....


private string GetColor()
{
    return lstColor.SelectedItem.ToString();
}

private string GetMake()
{
    return lstMake.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
private decimal GetPrice()
{
   decimal price;
   if(!decimal.TryParse(txtMaxPrice.Text, out price))
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid number");
   }
   return price;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed now, the usual copy/paste error

Answer (score 1):

You can't put functions *inside* other functions. Which is what you're doing - the first line of your quoted code, "private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)", is defining a function, and you're trying to put other functions inside it. You want the end } after "DisplayResult(strColor, strMake, decPrice);

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring methods within methods. 
Move the declaration of `DisplayResult`, `GetPrice`, `GetMake`, and `GetColor` out of the declaration for `btnSubmit_Click`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have a method inside a methods move it outside the button call

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strColor;
            string strMake;
            decimal decPrice;

            GetColor(ref strColor);
            GetMake(ref strMake);
            GetPrice(ref decPrice);
            DisplayResult(strColor, strMake, decPrice);
    }
private void GetColor(ref string color){
                color = lstColor.SelectedItem.ToString();
     }
   private void GetMake(ref string make){
                make = lstMake.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
   private void GetPrice(ref decimal price){
                if (decimal.TryParse(txtMaxPrice.Text, out price)){
                }
                else{
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid number");
                }
            }
   private void DisplayResult(string color, string make, decimal price){
                lblMessage.Text = "Color of " + color + " Make of: " + make + " " +price.ToString("c");
            }
```

Comment: I did this however the error of Use of unassigned variables remains.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with this code. Firstly, as others have said, you have tried to nest methods inside methods. The other problem is that you are using `ref` to pass values out of methods, rather than using a return type.

The methods to initialise strColor and strMake aren't really needed and can be "in-lined" and `GetPrice` can be improved by adding a return type to it.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strColor = lstColor.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string strMake = lstMake.SelectedItem.ToString();
    decimal decPrice = GetPrice(();
    DisplayResult(strColor, strMake, decPrice);
}

private decimal GetPrice()
{
    decimal price;
    if (!decimal.TryParse(txtMaxPrice.Text, out price))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid number");
    }

    return price;
}

private void DisplayResult(string color, string make, decimal price)
{
    lblMessage.Text = string.Format("Color of {0} Make of: {1} {2}",
                                    color, make, price.ToString("c"));
}
```